# SCNNode not showing in ARFrame's capturedImage

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scnnode, arscnview

I added a SCNNode to a ARSCNView:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
  guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return nil }
  guard let device = sceneView.device else { return nil }
  guard let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device, fillMesh: true) else { return nil }

  let faceNode = FaceNode(faceGeometry)

  // Node is a custom SCNNode class
  let glassesNode = Node(image: UIImage(named: "glasses")!, position: .glasses, anchor: faceAnchor)
  faceNode.addChildNode(glassesNode)

  return faceNode
 }
```

Then I use this delegate function to add a filter to each frame. The problem is the SCNNode that's added: `glassesNode` is not recognized in `frame.capturedImage`. Therefore, no filter is applied to the SCNNode, but is applied to everything else.

```
 func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

  guard let image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: frame.capturedImage)) else { return }

  let filterImage = setFilter(image)

  sceneView.scene.background.contents = context.createCGImage(filterImage, from: filterImage.extent)
 }
```

The only workaround is to use the `snapshot()` property of ARSCNView. Which works well. The SCNNode gets filtered, but there is too much latency with UI elements on the screen which is a problem.

Is there anyway I can use ARFrame's `capturedImage` and have it recognize the SCNNode that is on the ARSCNView?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using `capturedImage` of the ARFrame. ARKit itself is not aware that you are using SceneKit for rendering your 3D content, so the `capturedImage` will only contain the camera image itself.